# scale a QImage in Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, scale, qimage

What the easiest way to draw an image as a background for a `QGraphicsRectItem`?
I can set the background as follows but I can't scale the image:

```
 QGraphicsRectItem *enemyItem;

 QImage *image = new QImage(":/PaperMario.png");

 QBrush *brush = new QBrush(*image);


 enemyItem = new QGraphicsRectItem();
 enemyItem->setBrush(*brush);

 enemyItem->setRect(enemy->getXPos()*30,enemy->getYPos()*30,30,30);
 scene->addItem(enemyItem);
```

inside QGraphicsRectItem

```
void MySquare::setBrush(QColor _color){
    color = _color;
    color_pressed = _color;
    update(); //repaint
}
```

I have tried it using:

```
QBrush *brush = new QBrush(*image->scaled(10));
```

But I'm stuck: doesn't want to compile.
Is this the way to do it?

Edit:

```
    QImage *image = new QImage(":/PaperMario.png");
    QImage *scaled_image = new QImage(image->scaled(35,35,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    QBrush *brush = new QBrush(*scaled_image);
```

Does does draw it but it still shows the image multiple times in the drawing
[image]

Comment: Please don't "bundle" unrelated questions together. Every question is meant to have one good (i.e. "accepted") answer, and adding "Another question" makes that impossible.

Comment: I don't see how they are not related?

Comment: "What the easiest way to draw an image as a background for a QGraphicsRectItem?" and "Can I load .ico files in Qt?" are two different questions, and no single answer will apply to both.

Comment: Actually there is: I don't know. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you display your image in a scene (what i would guess) why dont you use `QGraphicsScene::addPixmap(QPixmap)` and use the `QPixmap::fromImage ( const QImage & image, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor )` to get your image into the right format.

Answer (score 0):

`*image->scaled(10)` does not work on a `QImage*`. Either you write `*image.scaled` or (better) `image->scaled`.

Comment: yeah figured that one out but thanks :) any idea why the image is repeating itself?

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke Set your scale flags as you want them. The docs explain the various flags (stretching, repeating, etc.)

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it working. By docs do you mean the enum Qt::TileRule?